# Blank page with a title in the center of the page

Tags: blank-page

I'm trying to do this but I really don't know how to do. I'm using a `\documentclass[12pt,a4]{book}`. I thought to use a chapter without the part of Chapter "number" because I want my index numeration in the center of the page like the image but now I think that isn't the solution.

Content of the image is what I want simulate.Thanks you!.

I can't put more code because I don't know how to start.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4]{book}


\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

[image: What I want simulate]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like you want to use `\part{Análisis}` to indicate a separate part of your book. `\part` is a standard sectioning command, one level above `\chapter`, and will appear numbered in the table of contents (the starred version `\part*` will just show the part title without the "Part *X*" text, and will not appear in the table of contents).